# Dropdown menu and add navbar option in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded a theme and customized it for my use, its a boostrap theme and i added navbar options according to my need but i m having two problems one is i am not able to create a dropdown menu in it and second it has limited navbar options like if i try to add options more than its space it get messy and create a new line of navbars, i want a small option button in right corner that will appear if there are more navbar than limit and it will dropdown remaining navbar options, i wonder if anybody can help me to sort out these two problems, pleas help me out this is very important project which i have to submit soon, here is my navbar code

```
<div class="row h_menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-left" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'index') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'academic') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="academic.php">Academic</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'about') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'contact') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'admission') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="login.php">Admission</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'faculty') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="faculty_cs.php">Faculty</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'downloads') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'gallery') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <!-- start soc_icons -->
    </nav>
    <div class="soc_icons navbar-right">
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/bbsulsindh"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/BBSULOfficial"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Navbar image:

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/s8a6z1j9p/

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are looking for something like this
http://codepen.io/snm/pen/RrbmVV?editors=101

Comment: yeah something like that but its not working i added dropdown menu from your given code but thats not working and see how it shows up now
http://postimg.org/image/g2waj5011/